# Windows Explorer Favorites separator bar?

Tags: windows-7, links, favorites

Seems like on the Internet there's no solution for Windows 7 Favorites bar separator?

It's really confusing when there are so much links. I want to group it and separate it to make it easier to find, any ideas?

Btw, I think using blank folder/exe file is a dumb approach and also the separate distance is too big.

[image: Windows Explorer Favorites]

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a new text file where it doesn't disturb you named like:

- ----------------
- ================

  or with [Box Drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_Drawing) characters:
- ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
- ────────────────
- ════════════════
- ┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
- ┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅
- ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
- ┉┉┉┉┉┉┉┉┉┉┉┉┉┉┉┉

2) Drag&Drop this file to the `C:\Users\<your user>\Links` folder repeatedly.

3) Arrange the so created shortcuts in the [image] Favorites in your Explorer.

4) Add `␣(1)` to the first shortcut's name for consistency.

Comment: Sorry, is it work only for windows 7? I tried it on windows 10 quick access but not working.

Comment: @AbrahamPutraPrakasa You tagged the question with [tag:windows-7]. I don't have 10 (or 8[.1]).

Comment: My bad, this was so old.. but i will try on windows 7, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can uncheck "Favorites" in folder option found in your control panel. If you don't want other link folder showing.

Comment: Sorry but I need those other link, but I just need some separators between links for better productivity